# UDPclient buffer too small

Tags: vb.net, sockets, udp, udpclient

Hello to all I am developing an application that needs to send a image via the UDP socket.I know that TCP is a better protocol,but playing with Kryonet in Java I have learnt that UDP is better for this type of application.I have this small class that I have made:

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text.Encoding

Public Class BasicUDPClient
    Event ClientMessageReceived(ByVal msg() As Byte)

    Public Property HostName As String = "localhost"
    Public Property Port As Integer = 8991

    Dim sender As New UdpClient(0)
    Dim receiver As New UdpClient(Port)
    Dim th_recv As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Receive)
    Dim run As Boolean
    Dim ep As New IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 0)
    Public Sub New(ByVal host As String, ByVal port As Integer)
        HostName = host
        Me.Port = port
        receiver.Client.Blocking = False
        '10485760 = 10MB
        receiver.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 10485760
        sender.Client.SendBufferSize = 10485760
        receiver.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000
        StartReceive()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SendString(ByVal msg As String)
        SendMessage(UTF8.GetBytes(msg))
    End Sub

    Public Sub SendMessage(ByVal msg() As Byte)
        sender.Connect(HostName, Port)
        sender.Send(msg, msg.Length)
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartReceive()
        run = True
        th_recv = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Receive)
        th_recv.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub StopReceive()
        run = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Receive()
        While (run)
            Try
                RaiseEvent ClientMessageReceived(receiver.Receive(ep))
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
            End Try

        End While
    End Sub

End Class
```

It works great with string likes hello,but when I am sending the image,about 200000-150000 bytes I got an error saying that the buffer is lower than the contents of the packet (I can post an image of the error message,but my .net language is in Spanish)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. With UDP you cannot send messages bigger than 64KB. Use TCP, or split the payload yourself into multiple messages which will be extremely complex because messages can be lost.
2. ReceiveBufferSize is not what you think it is. It almost never helps to use it.
3. Code for sender and receiver is missing but `sender.Connect` looks strange given that UDP is connectionless.

Comment: So,the only way to send it is spliting the image,no?

Comment: The answer to this comment is given in bullet 1. Not sure what to add. Any concrete questions?

Comment: @KePimbo: UDP is message-oriented, and messages have a finite amount of bytes they can hold.  TCP is stream-oriented, and does not have that limitation. So yes, you must split large data into smaller messages when using UDP. There are protocols, like TFTP, that handle that for you.

Comment: @usr: `Connect()` has meaning in UDP. Just like in TCP, it creates an association between local and remote IP/Port pairs. One benefit of this is that a "connected" UDP socket can report ICMP-based errors, like "destination port not reachable", which you can't get with an "unconnected" UDP socket, you would have to use a RAW socket to receive them (and that has administration restrictions on it).